# What is the name of that white, dark blue/purple, and black slideshow presentation format/template?

Tags: presentation, formatting, latex

What is the name of that dark blue/purple border, white background, black sans serif text (except for the heading text, which is white on a dark blue/purple background) slideshow presentation format/template? It is sometimes used in the physical sciences, mathematics and philosophy.

Comment: You should at least consider *not* using latex/beamer for your presentations if that's on option in your field. https://better-scientific-presentations.blogspot.com/2012/04/on-why-i-hate-latexbeamer.html
https://matusiak.eu/numerodix/blog/2007/11/28/latex-sucks/
http://people.irisa.fr/Tomofumi.Yuki/beamer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess most slideshows you have seen are made with the [beamer package of LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)). One of the default themes matches your description.

Here's a brief introduction in Overleaf, including illustrations: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer

Comment: Thanks, that's the one. I've selected yours as the approved answer, but I can't upvote with my account yet.